# Showing Month-Year from Date, in Query for SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, reporting-services

I'm currently using SSRS to connect to Adempiere (postgresql)

In query, i'm trying to just extract the Month-Year data from the Date so i can use it for Pivot Table/Matrix purposes.

However, when i use this

```
> SELECT        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, adempiere.c_invoice.dateinvoiced, 0),
> 
> FROM            adempiere.c_invoice
```

I get an error like this

```
>SQL Execution Error
>
>Excuted SQL statement: SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,dateinvoiced,0)
>
> FROM adempere.c_invoice 
>
>Error Source: PSQLODBC.DLL Error Message:
>
> ERROR [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"; 
>
>Error while executing query
```

I've searched high and low and before realising if my problem was a unique problem. Maybe it isnt but i hope someone can help me if im steering in the wrong direction or there's some work around

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are querying a Postgres database, you obviously cannot use `dateadd()` which is SQL-Server specific.

Use a Postgres function like:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', dateinvoiced) AS month_year1
      ,to_char(dateinvoiced, 'MM-YYYY')  AS month_year2
FROM   adempiere.c_invoice
```

Whatever fits your vague definition `Month-Year` better.
The first yields a `timestamp` truncated to month-accuracy. [More about `date_trunc()` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)
The second yields a `text` of the pattern `06-2013`. [More about `to_char()` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: I would like to know, since this is a Postgres database, will there be alot of Postgres-specific function that cant be used in SQL Server? And are these functions only limited to just the Query section, or other parts of the SSRS? thanks again :)

Comment: I don't use SSRS myself. Any interaction with the Postgres DB has to use the Postgres dialect of SQL - which is closer to the SQL standard than SQL Server.